# How to make colour tables in QGIS to use in multiple projects?

Tags: qgis, colortable

I would like to know how to make a colour table that can be saved and used across many projects. I am using this to colour rock types, for example:
Rock one=blue
Rock two= yellow
Rock three= red
etc. I have many rock types and want to ensure that the colouring is the same for all projects. Is there a simple way to apply a universal colour table across many projects?

Comment: Is this for a categorical raster or vector data (points, polygons)?

Answer (score 2):

You want to save the layer style.

1. Save your layer as a shapefile,
2. Open the Layer Properties | Style tab
3. Click the Save style button and select "QGIS Layer Style File", then save it with the same name

[Saving vector layer with specific symbology using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77069/saving-vector-layer-with-specific-symbology-using-qgis)

A guide can be found here : http://www.qgisforum.org/qgis-tutorial/layer-properties/save-load-style