# Is there any way to include "universal" style/symbology in GeoPackage?

Tags: qgis, style, saga, geopackage

I am just playing with the GeoPackage format in QGIS. In QGIS it works nice with the style saved from QGIS but if I load it for example in SAGA the style is not applied.

Is there any way to include at least some basic style (for example point colors for value ranges or classes) so it could be used by different applications?
Or is the included style always "application-specific"?

Comment: You could add columns to the attribute table for color, symbol shape, etc.

Comment: but the user has to built a new style from them manually - am I right?

Comment: It depends on the program. In QGIS, if you use the same column names in multiple layers, you can create one style and load it for each layer. So it saves you a few steps, but you still have to create the style in the same program. I don't use SAGA, so I'm not sure how it would work with that program.

Comment: I know that I can easily copy style in QGIS and easily use copy of the same qml file for several shp layers to load them with the style in QGIS. I also know that I can save the QGIS style to Geopackage to be applied same way as the qml with shp. However I was curious whether the Geopackage standard also contains some universal style definitions which is compatible in more apps supporting Geopackage format.

Comment: Is it possible to do this by python code ?

Answer (score 17):

QGIS support its own format QML and SLD. When you use GeoPackage (or PostGIS) you can save the style on the GeoPackage and distribute both the data and the style. On the layer properties, the **Style** button has an **Save Style** option and you can choose **Save in database (GeoPackage)**.

[image]

The style is saved on a table inside your GeoPackage called `layer_styles`. The style is saved as QML (on `styleQML` column) and also saved as SLD (on `styleSLD` column).

[image]

Other softwares, like SAGA, GeoTools, etc, could support this same approach, reading the `layer_styles` table, if present, and use the SLD style stored in the GeoPackage.

Try to convince SAGA developers to support SLD. If SAGA gets SLD support, we could use and share the SLD style saved on the GeoPackage.

Comment: Can you post a small bit about how you save the style to geopackage?

Comment: I've added more details about saving the style in the database to the answer.

Comment: OK, thanks for the information about saving SLD in the GPG - I thought it just adds the QML which is QGIS-only. I will ask my friend to load my files in other programs to see which other are able to load the SLD style.

Comment: If I could now find a way how to use the SLD in `layer_styles` in ArcMap, I would be all set to work in a mixed environment. Apparently, an unsolved problem for years now?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the GUI has changed since jgrocha's answer.
I thought there must have been something wrong with my QGIS or the way I was loading gpkg layers, since I couldn't see the option to "Save in Database".

The option is now available in a drop-down *after* you select "Save current style" or "Save multiple styles":
[image]
[image]

It saves styles to the gpkg in both QML and SLD format.

Answer (score 0):

> On the layer properties, the Style button has an Save Style option and
> you can choose Save in database (GeoPackage)

This works only for layers already in a geopackage though. You cannot load a shapefile, style it, and use a geopackage to store the styling. So you cannot, for instance, use a geopackage to store and circulate a collection of styles.