# save QGIS style as SVG

Tags: qgis

I have a set of layers with a certain symbology for each. Is it possible to save the style or only the symbol as SVG file?

Answer (score 2):

QGIS can save the style only as a Layer Style File, SLD or in a database (*sorry for my user interface seen below not being in English*), as explained in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/77073/13426) answer.

[image]

If you want to edit or work with the symbols elsewhere, you can always open the Print Composer, export the map as an SVG file and get them from there.